# Fold Transition Slideshow in Android just like iOS MPFold Transitions

Tags: android, ios, android-animation

i want to implement Fold Transition in android for more multiple images by one by one just like iOS MPFold Transitions 
the link for for iOS MPFold Transitions [iOS MPFold Transitions](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition)
And i want exactly same for in android, i tried the [devBytes fold animation](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/devbytes/graphics/FoldingLayout/res/layout/activity_fold.xml) (But it works only one image and i want for multiple image) can anyone suggest a solution for this.